# Grouping age in database

Tags: sql, database, grouping

I have designed my database and all is well. Within the database I have an Age column.

One of the requirements is that Age must be grouped into categories 1-12, 13-17, 18-25, 26-35 etc for easy selection.

I am a bit stumped with how to do this? I have not been asked to actually implement the database, only design the ERD.

I'm not sure if this is enough info for someone to answer, so if you need anything more please just ask.

**EDIT:**

I have been told that I do not have to allow for changing ages over time.

Comment: Given that age changes with time, if your age column represents the current age, you have a problem.

Comment: @DanBracuk sorry, I have been asked not to take into account that users age will change over time.

Comment: @user2447832: That doesn't sound like a real-world requirement then. More like some academic task / homework. If that's the case, all is fine. If that's not the case, you really should question this requirement.

Comment: @DanBracuk is right, you should not store the age but birthdate and calculate age from there.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth you're right, it is just a task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a better solution than adding a new column to the data is simply to define a view on the original table:

```
create view vw_customer as (
    select c.*,
           (case when Age between 1 and 12 then '1-12'
                 when Age between 13 and 17 then '13-17'
                 when Age between 18 and 25 then '18-25'
                 when Age between 26-35 then '26-35'
            end) as AgeGroup
    from c;
```

Another alternative, if your database supports it, is computed columns.  There seems little reason why such derived data should actually be stored with the data, when SQL provides other alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding another column that is called something along the lines of AgeBracket to minimise information loss.

You could then do one of two things
1) have an update statement (or do it on the insert)...

```
UPDATE customer 
SET AgeBracket = case when Age<=12 then '1-12' when Age<=17 then '13-17' .... end
WHERE AgeBracket IS NULL
-- alternative approach    
INSERT INTO Customer(Name,Age,AgeBracket) 
VALUES(@Name, @Age, case when @Age<=12 then '1-12' ....end)`
```

or 2) you could create a lookup table which has the structure `MaxAge , AgeBracketLabel` and join it where `Age<=MaxAge` and refer to the label - this is useful if/when it becomes more complex or more information about the brackets is required

Comment: Hi Steph, thank you, could you show me how I would do so in the insert?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth You could embed it in a view too - that's perfectly feasible, but I prefer putting stuff in the db directly so that I don't have to take into account view performance and so that I don't end up with people building their own calculations if they don't notice the view but want the column anyway.

Comment: @StephLocke: That's basically data de-normalization. If not handled with care, you will easily end up with de-synchronized data. In other words: For the reasons you stated, I think it is a pretty bad idea.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth You're right - if the CASE route is taken, it's denormalization, but if the lookup table route is taken it is normalised.  That being said you are very right about it needing to be hadnled with care - this'd be a prime example of business logic that needs to be maintained and have clear processes around maintaining it.

Comment: @StephLocke: Yes, I was just talking about the CASE eh.. case. Sorry for not being explicit.

Comment: @StephLocke Thank you very much! Would this change how I display it in the ERD? From what I gather I would just add AgeBracket?

Comment: Yes, unless you went with a lookup table option in which it would be another entity with a 1-m relationship

Comment: @StephLocke sorry to keep asking for more, but (last time) would you be able to show me the CREATE statement for that table you are inserting into?

Comment: @user2447832, depends on specific RDBMS but something along the lines of `create table customer (cust_id int, name varchar(45), age int, agebracket varchar(15), primary key(cust_id))`